# Case, Subquery, and Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What I'm trying to do is get avg tip_portion for all rides that are above average time, average time, and below average time. So return 3 lines. When I run this it says:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "trip_data"
LINE 11: on trip_data.trip_id= trip_data.trip_id
```

I've changed it to `trip_data.trip_id= a.trip_id` it says:

```
 ERROR:  column a.trip_id does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong. Can I do this a simpler way?

```
select 
    AVG(tip / total_fare) as tip_portion, trip_time
from
    (
        select 
            avg(trip_time),
                case
                    when avg(trip_time) > 11.05 then 'Above Average'
                    when avg(trip_time) = 11.05 then 'Average'
                    when avg(trip_time) < 11.05 then 'Below Average'
                end as trip_time_group
        from
            trip_data
    ) as a
        join
    trip_fare ON trip_fare.trip_id = trip_data.trip_id
where
    pickup_date <> '2009-12-25'
group by trip_time;
```

Comment: Where does 11.05 comefrom

Comment: Its just a number I am using as average trip time. It means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any `trip_id` column in your subquery. Also, you should put 
`trip_data.trip_id= a.trip_id` instead of `trip_fare.trip_id= trip_data.trip_id` as the `trip_data` does not exist in the main query.

Comment: Why would I need to return the trip_id column anywhere? I just want it to join trip_fare and and trip_data.

Comment: In the main query the `trip_data` table doesn't exist. The tables are `trip_fare` and `a`. As `a`is the result of a subquery, how do you expect that `a`had a column called `trip_id`if you don't return any column called `trip_id` from your subquery?

Comment: If I ask the subquery to return trip_id then wouldn't I have to use it in a groupby statement.  Its a unique key so I don't want to group by it.

Comment: So the question is, why do you need to join that tables by the `trip_id`? That doesn't make sense

Comment: i need to join them because `tip` and `total fare` are in `trip_fare` table and `trip_time` is in `trip_data`. `trip_id` is a unique identifier that will make sure my `trip_time` is matched up to the corresponding `trip_fare` from the other table

Comment: @TimPilo The subquery doesn't have `GROUP BY`, so it just returns one row containing the average of all trip times. There's nothing to join on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `CASE` from the subquery into the main query.

```
SELECT AVG(tip/total_fare) AS tip_portion,
        CASE WHEN trip_time > avg_trip_time THEN 'Above Average'
             WHEN trip_time = avg_trip_time THEN 'Average'
             ELSE 'Below Average'
        END AS trip_time_group
FROM trip_fare
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(trip_time) AS avg_trip_time
            FROM trip_data) AS a
GROUP BY trip_time_group
```